# How do I write .not(this) to include all previous DIVs to this, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a tree structure menu. What I am trying to achieve is to add the '.toggle-me' class to the next submenu that shows up.

I have achieved this to some degree, although I need to some get the `.not(this)` to include all `.rtmenu`'s before `this`?

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
$('.rtmenu').live('click', function(){ 
    $('.rtmenu:visible').not(this).addClass('toggle-me'); 
    $('.toggle-me').toggle()
});
```

Please let me know if you need clarification. Much Appreciated, Thanks

Comment: @Codesleuth - Sorry, I tried & it didn't work

Comment: I read the question wrong and deleted the comment. My apologies for that!

Comment: You're talking about a tree, so can you define what "before" and "previous" mean?  All previous siblings, parents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try wrapping `this` with jQuery, since `this` is not a jQuery object:

```
$('.rtmenu:visible').not($(this)).addClass('toggle-me');
```

Additionally, i would omit the `toggle-me` class. You could simply write:

```
$('.rtmenu:visible').not($(this)).toggle();
```

Comment: I have tried but wrapping this makes no difference...I need to select all div.rtmenu prev to `this`

Comment: Can you show me some HTML? This would make this a lot easier.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that isn't the issue, `.not(this)` works well.

Comment: I just need some way to exclude div.rtmenu previous to `this`

Comment: How is the hierarchy structured? Are all relevant elements children of a single element, or are they nested somehow? If they are not nested, you could simply use `$(this).prevAll('.rtmenu:visible')` to select them.